# CSS clip string based on width sibling image width

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to clip (using ellipses) a string without defining an absolute width?
I know the following class will work if I set an absolute width:

```
div {
width: 200px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

However, I want the width of the text to be clipped (with ellipses) if it exceeds the width of the following image:

```
<div>@graphic.Name</div>
<img src="@graphic.ApplicationFilePath" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap both element into the same wrapper that you make `inline-block`.
You make the text position absolute so that only the image will define the width of the container and you stretch the text to that width using `left`/`right`

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.container > div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container > img {
  margin-top:20px; /*you need to adjust this depending on the height of the text*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>this is a long long text</div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?image=1069">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>this is a long long text</div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150?image=1069">
</div>
```